# how to replace some text and again assign it to same string in c#

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

In my application I will get the file name with `-b`. I need to replace the `-b` and after replacing it I need to again add that filename to the doc. How can I do this?

The filename in doc is `123-b.docx`, I need to replace the `-b`,  then after replacment I should get `123.doc` this should be given to doc.

```
if (ddlstype.SelectedValue == "1")
{
    doc = filup1.FileName;
    if (doc.ToLower().Replace("-b", "").ToString())
    {

    }

    ReadFiles(doc1, doc2, ""); 
}
else if (ddlstype.SelectedValue == "2")
{   
    ReadFiles(doc1, "" , ""); 
}
else if (ddlstype.SelectedValue == "3")
{       
    ReadFiles(doc1,"", doc2); 
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `string` to `bool` near:
>   `if (doc.ToLower().Replace("-b", "").ToString())`

Comment: Why you using `.ToString()` there?

Comment: if i am removing tostring() also i am getting the same error

Comment: You getting this error because `doc.ToLower().Replace("-b", "").ToString()` is not bool.

Comment: [if else msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h(VS.80).aspx) you might need to check..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
doc = doc.ToLower().Replace("-b", "");
```

Remove the `if.` So it would be:

```
if (ddlstype.SelectedValue == "1")
{
    doc = filup1.FileName;
    doc = doc.ToLower().Replace("-b", "");

    ReadFiles(doc1, doc2, ""); 
}
```

I remove `if` since `if statement are selection statements`, which means it checks your statement if its true or false. So declaring the value of the variable `doc` should not be on if statements.

Comment: Done, if this solves your problem, you can now accept it as an answer as reference to others. Thanks! @bargavik93

Comment: my file uploader allows multiple selection when i insert data in data base and that inserted data
is displayed in gridview how can i make that file uploader multiple selection false when editing the records in gridview

Comment: Hi @bargavik93, I guess you need to post it as a new question, since I need to see the code regarding your question.

Comment: it is question no 46110964 when i click edit button in gridview then multiple file uploader should become single file upload control

Comment: hi can you please answer my question in 46110964

Answer (score 1):

ToString() returns a string and you are using it in an if statement. That is why you are getting a compile error. An if statement requires something which is either true or false inside eg:

```
if (a==4)
{ 
  ...
```

ToString() does not return something true or false. It returns a string.

What are you trying to check for in your if statement?

Comment: Thanks @Mafii. Typed it on a phone so all lines automatically begin with capitals...